# Help understanding this handwritten Japanese sentence

Tags: handwriting

Could you help me understand what is handwritten in this image? It is taken from a manga about boxing.

[image]

My attempt:

> 左ボディ→左アッパー右フック
>   上(?)の打ち分け
>   オー(?)ックス(?)コンビネーション
>   を得意とする　サンデーパンチ

Comment: The OP is not asking for translation, obviously he doesn't understand the words on the manga, as stated in his question.

Comment: @DavidWashington "Questions asking for translations, **transcriptions** or proofreading are off-topic"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - 「オーソドックスなコンビネーションを得意とする」
> - 「上下の打ち分け」 : 「左ボディ→左アッパー」
> - 「**サンデーパンチ**」(止{とど}めの一発{いっぱつ})は「右フック」
>     止めの一発 means a punch that is thrown to gain a knockout.

- He is good at basic boxing combinations. / He is good at boxing combinations sticking to the basics.
- Throwing punches high and low, or Going up and down: A left-hand body blow to A left uppercut
- His **Sunday punch** is a right hook!

**Sunday punch**:
＜US English＞ the most powerful and effective punch of a boxer, especially the punch used in trying to gain a knockout

**サンデーパンチ**: [san-dê panchi]
<日本語 Japanese>
その選手が最も得意とするパンチのこと。
the punch that a boxer is good at most

[Reference](https://www.expertboxing.com/boxing-basics/how-to-box/7-basic-boxing-combinations): How to Box > 7 Basic Boxing Combinations

[image]

Answer (score 5):

左ボディ→左アッパー右フック
上**下**の打ち分け
オー**ソド**ックス**な**コンビネーション
を得意とする　サンデーパンチ

Answer (score 3):

I believe in “上(?)の打ち分け” the (?) is 下 as in “上下の打ち分け”